# calling user defined function in jQuery live

Tags: jquery, live, user-defined-functions

I defined a function and called it in live click event, but the function runs without click event. the code is this :

```
function validate(flag){
   //do something
}
$('#btnYes').live('click', validate(1));
```

The validate function runs on page load before any click. What's the problem?

Comment: try wrapping it in an anonymous call - `$('#btnYes').on('click', function(){validate(i);})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the other answer will do what you need I highly recommend not using the `live()` method as it is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) I recommend using the `on()` method, where you coud write it like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnYes", function(){ validate(1); });
```

Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: yes it does, you can attach an event handler to a parent element and  pass the id or class that will be applied for whether they are created dinamically

Comment: That's great! and I found a way to pass the parameter to the function : $(document).on('click', '#btnYes', {flag:1}, validate);
and get the parameter in the function like this : function validate(params){alert(params.data.flag);}

Comment: nice one! I'm glad it was helpful:) , if you think this was helpful please consider upvoting and accepting the anwser so it remains useful for other users

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a function reference and not call the function.

```
$('#btnYes').live('click', validate);
```

`live` will call `validate` for you when a click event is raised.

However, you can not pass the flag in this case. So you must still resort to using an anonymous function.

```
$('#btnYes').live('click', function() { validate(1); });
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I wrote in the second way, I didn't pay attention to the function reference point.

Answer (score 0):

found a way to pass the parameters to the function by on method :

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnYes', {flag:1}, validate);
```

and get the parameter in the function like this :

```
function validate(params){
    alert(params.data.flag);
}
```